# String.find is not returning any value

Tags: python, string

I am trying to substring the following value to get the link(image value) out of it:

```
<p>This is a recipe developed by my wife, Irene. It&rsquo;s been tweaked to perfection. I've never ordered congee in Manila since then.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
(img src="http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/6047/69934653.jpg" alt="" >
</p>
```

I tried the following :

```
thumb = item.xpath('description')[0].text // To get the vaue from XML
            pos = thumb.find('http')   // Find http: and then Substring
            Log('Position HTTP'+pos)
            thumb = thumb[:pos]
            Log('Thumb Details'+thumb)
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `thumb` is actually the string you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.find()` returns int, so `Log('Position HTTP'+pos)` will raise `TypeError`.

Change to `Log('Position HTTP %s' % pos)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider using the Regex module instead:
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

```
import re
match = re.search('http://\S+.(?:jpeg|jpg|png)', a_string)
print match.group(0)
```